# In ExtJS 4, how to retan grid value after drag and drop between grids?

Tags: extjs

Based on the example off the Extjs 4 site i gor the grid to grid DnD working, but I need to retain the source grid value ( in the example it is automatically getting deleted). The link to the example:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/dd/dnd_grid_to_grid.html

I dont see any part in the code where the data from he source grid is getting deleted. Is it done automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use `allowCopy` and `copy` in the `viewConfig`. It won't work if you put it in the grid config or plugin config.

Answer (score 0):

Set `allowCopy:true` and copy:true for grid view of source grid.
then it will copy from source grid and paste in destination grid.

Comment: hmm...doesnt seem to work. I used allowCopy:true and copy:true in the source grid

Answer (score 0):

just put the viewConfig in ur Grid View file as below :

**viewConfig**: { **copy: true**, plugins: { } }

this allows your source Datastore to retain n only copies the record to target on DND actions.